# Line chart from list

Tags: c#, list, linechart

I'm trying to plot a line chart from a list of object position in C#. The list stores current position of an object. It is updated every 0.1 second and new item is added to list every few sec. according to user setting. In one second more than one item can be updated. I save the data to file, and it works fine when I copy it to Excel and make chart manually. The thing is I need to do it inside program.

Here is the code.

```
List<int> pas = new List<int>();
```

Every few sec. the item is added to the list.

```
private void tm1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            pas.Add(-120);
    }
```

Then, every 0.1 items from list are moved and the list is saved

```
private void tm2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            moveQueue();
            saveToFile();
        }
```

Save method:

```
public void saveToFile()
        {
            foreach (var v in pas)
            {
                wynik += v.ToString() + "\t";

            }
            wynik += Environment.NewLine;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@path_txt, wynik);
        }
```

What is in moveQueue is meaningless. It just take each item and move it.
The output copied to excel looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWgvk.jpg)
And the chart I'm supposed to plot should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgHX3.jpg)

I should add, that the graph must be plotted dynamicly in real time, so than the user can see it.

I know that I have to add x axis variable, but after that I have to idea how to do it.

Comment: This is one of my favorite resource for simple charts in C# using the standard .net framework.  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61 It should give you a good steer in the right direction.  And another tutorial for real time chart data: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh297119(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks, that helped me somehow

Comment: Glad it did. Please give it a +1.